# How to draw coastal borders for countries

Tags: r, gis

I want to draw countries, highlighting their coastal borders. I have the following technique, which *almost* works.

```
library(rworldmap)
library(rgeos)
library(maps)

data("countriesCoarseLessIslands")
data("coastsCoarse")

country <- "Argentina"

countryOutline <- countriesCoarseLessIslands[countriesCoarseLessIslands$NAME %in% country,]
maps::map(countryOutline,col="light grey",fill=TRUE,border=0)
coastalBorder <- gIntersection(coastsCoarse,countryOutline)
plot(coastalBorder, col="blue",lwd=2,add=TRUE)
```

Output:

[image]

There are two aspects I'd like to improve.

First, how can I get rid of the discontinuities in the coasts (see the image for Argentina). Is there a function or method (in rgeos or wherever) which allows for fuzziness in determining the the overlap?

Second, how can I do something similar with a higher resolution map polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is very fine, you just need to reduce the scale using `setScale` for `gIntersection` to be more tolerant:

```
library(rworldmap)
library(rgeos)
library(maps)

data("countriesCoarseLessIslands")
data("coastsCoarse")

country <- "Argentina"

countryOutline <- countriesCoarseLessIslands[countriesCoarseLessIslands$NAME %in% country,]
maps::map(countryOutline,col="light grey",fill=TRUE,border=0)

setScale(1e+04) # Change Tolerance to avoid dicontinuities

coastalBorder <- gIntersection(coastsCoarse,countryOutline)
plot(coastalBorder, col="blue",lwd=2,add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much. Hadn't noted the ability to set scale for tolerance.